# Sizeof C array with integers (in Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, c-preprocessor

myclass.h:

```
#define BUTTON_NAVI 41;
#define BUTTON_SETTINGS 42;
#define BUTTON_INFO 43;
```

myclass.m:

```
int btnNavi = BUTTON_NAVI;
int btnSettings = BUTTON_SETTINGS;
int btnArray[2] = {btnNavi, btnSettings};
NSLog(@"count = %i", sizeof(btnArray));
[self addToolbarButtons:btnArray];
```

-> Log: count = 8

8?! What did I do wrong?

And inside "addToolbarButtons" count is 4... :-(

**EDIT:**

```
- (void)addToolbarButtons:(int[])buttonIdArray {
    NSLog(@"count = %i", sizeof(buttonIdArray));
}
```

-> Log: count = 4

Comment: Pretty sure those semicolons aren't supposed to be there in the defines, not that they should alter any of your code's behavior though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` is giving you the size in bytes, 8 bytes sounds right for 2 integers (32-bit or 4 bytes each).

If what you want is the *length* of the array, you can do `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` which will give you the size of the entire array divided by the size of each element. In this case you will get `8 / 4 == 2`, which is what I take it you expect.

**EDIT**
To answer your second question, when you pass the array to the method, you're actually passing a *pointer* to the array. Hence, the size of the pointer is also 32-bits or 4 bytes. If you want the function to know the length of the array, you need to also pass its length along with said pointer.

Comment: Thanks! But why I get "4" in "addToolbarButtons"? (I edit my question)

Comment: If Obj-C behaves like C in this respect (I think it does), it's because `addToolbarButtons` receives a pointer value representing the address of the first element in the array.  C semantics are such that expressions of array type are implicitly converted to pointer type in most circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` is giving the size of the array in bytes. An int is 4 bytes, so a 2-element array of ints will be 8 bytes.

However, `sizeof` won't do what you want in your method. When a C array is passed into a function (or method), it actually get passed as a pointer, and `sizeof` will return the size of a pointer. You should modify your method to take a length parameter:

```
- (void)addToolbarButtons:(int *)buttonIdArray length:(size_t)len
{
    NSLog(@"count = %d", len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator gives you the size in bytes of the thing you pass to it. If an `int` is 4 bytes, then an array of two `int`s is 8 bytes.

However, `sizeof` is a compile-time check on the variable itself. At runtime, the bounds of an array are not known — nor are they known outside the scope where the variable was defined. When you declare the argument `(int[])buttonIdArray`, the compiler desugars that to `(int *)buttonArray` — it's just a plain int pointer. So when you do `sizeof(buttonArray)`, it tells you the size of a pointer, 4.

Because the language doesn't keep track of their size for you, using C arrays is a pain. You have to pass the number of elements in the array to every function and method that acts on it.